# wpf combobox multibinding to xml file strange error

Tags: wpf, xml, combobox, multibinding

I have run into a strange problem with my combobox displaying a list of the world countries. I am using a XML (AllCountries.xml) file as my datasource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<countries>
  <country>
    <iso>AF</iso>
    <name>Afghanistan</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso>AL</iso>
    <name>Albania</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso>DZ</iso>
    <name>Algeria</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso>AS</iso>
    <name>American Samoa</name>
  </country>
  <country>
    <iso>AD</iso>
    <name>Andorra</name>
  </country> etc
```

My combobox XAML looks like this:

```
<ComboBox 
      Width="200"
      SelectedValuePath="Country"
      ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/countries/country/name}">
      <ComboBox.DataContext>
         <XmlDataProvider x:Name="Dataxml" Source="\Content\AllCountries.xml" />
      </ComboBox.DataContext>
</ComboBox>
```

And everything works great: I see Afghanistan, Albania, Algerie +++ . OK, so I want to have the associated (iso) code displayed in the dropdown like this:

Afghanistan, AF

Albania, AL

Algerie, DZ

and so on. To achieve this I add this ItemTemplate to my combobox:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock>
               <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
                          <Binding XPath="/countries/country/name" />
                          <Binding XPath="/countries/country/iso" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
          </TextBlock>
     </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

When running the application everything seems ok - until I click on the combobox and see the following list displayed:

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF

Afghanistan, AF
....

:-( Something is obviously wrong with my XPath multibinding but i cannot figure it out. What's going on here???

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/countries/country}"
```

with

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
    <Binding XPath="name" />
    <Binding XPath="iso" />
</MultiBinding>
```

because then each `ComboBoxItem` has a country as `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set the `ItemTemplate` so as to host 2 `TextBlocks` inside and databind each with the path!

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath="/countries/country/name" }" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath="/countries/country/iso" }" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Sorry Manolis - your solution gives "The object 'DataTemplate' already has a child and cannot add 'TextBlock'. 'DataTemplate' can accept only one child."

But thanks anyways for trying to help - i apperciate it!